# name must be a namespace name Visual Studio Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to run the following code and convert the RGB image to YCbCr color model. But when building this code segment it gives the above error. I have attached a screenshot. Can you refer that and give me a solution.

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "iostream"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv2;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat src1;
    src1 = imread("face.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    namedWindow("Original image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Original image", src1);

    Mat gray, edge, draw;
    //cvtColor(src1, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat imgYCC = cv2.cvtColor(src1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB);

    //equalizeHist(gray, draw);
    //Canny(gray, edge, 50, 255, 3);
    edge.convertTo(draw, CV_8U);
    namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("image", imgYCC);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: it means that no namespace `cv2` exists. I think you can call `cvtColor()` without the `cv2.`.

Comment: In C++, namespaces are not used with a dot but `::` like `cv::cvtColor(src1, cv::COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace `cv2` doesn't exists. It's the name of the python wrapper.

Just remove the line:

```
using namespace cv2;
```

and don't use it in your code, e.g.:

```
Mat imgYCC = cvtColor(src1, COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB);
```